# giving the choice to my user to choose where he wants to save his file access

Tags: ms-access, vba

My question is about opening the document file.
I want to give the choice to my user to choose where he wants to save his file.
However, I may be wrong but I use a FileDialog (msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
which opens the file normally and afterwards sends me an error message !! I start in programming thank  you for help.

this my code

```
Public Function ObtenirCheminFichier(path As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim filePath As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    ObtenirCheminFichier = path

    If Not fso.FileExists(path) Then
        Dim tmpPath As String
        tmpPath = Replace(Replace(path, ".\", "", , 1), "\", "", 1, 0)
        'ObtenirCheminFichier = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show()
      ' ObtenirCheminFichier = CurrentProject.path & "\" & tmpPath
         ObtenirCheminFichier = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) & "\" & tmpPath
    End If
End Function
```

and i doubt error this

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Categorie_C2_req", acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, spath, True
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `.SelectedItems(1)` after the folder picker like this:
`Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)`

For further details about FileDialog object you can check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.FileDialog)

As you want to open a single file I suggest you to add this line before opening the file dialog: `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).AllowMultiSelect = False`